# Issue during inserting data in sql database

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert some data into SQL database using a python script, but I am facing an error, I am not sure why.
Here is what I am doing

```
create_query = """INSERT INTO bcmdb.bcmdbuser.Groups (ParentGroupID, ChildGroupID, DirectChild) 
                           VALUES (100, ?, 0) """
record = (id_s)
cursor.execute(create_query, record)
conn.commit()
```

I am using "pypyodbc" to connect to database and its working fine, the issue this code produce is

> TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple or Row.

In `cursor.execute(create_query, record)` line specifically.

Any idea will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with one-valued tuples in Python. They **must** have a trailing comma.
Try like this:

```py
create_query = """INSERT INTO bcmdb.bcmdbuser.Groups (ParentGroupID, ChildGroupID, DirectChild) 
                           VALUES (100, ?, 0) """
record = (id_s,)
cursor.execute(create_query, record)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: wow this worked cant believe it was this trivial i feel really stupid right now, thanks so much for answering!